# Как создать keytool?

Tags: java, android-studio, vue.js, cordova, quasar-framework

Я пробую создать приложение на quasar (cordova)
https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-cordova-a...
При формировании ключа keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 20000
выдает ошибку
"keytool" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Тогда я захожу в C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin
Пытаюсь повторить эту команду по этом уадресу.
Но После заполнения формы происходит
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ввожу пароль и мне отказано в доступе.
Я не могу создать через build- generate signed bundle т.к. у меня отсутствует данная строка в Android studio
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь выдает такую ошибку.
Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

> "keytool" не является внутренней или внешней командой

Эта ошибка возникает из-за того, командная оболочка не может найти команду. Устранить можно трема способами:

1. запускать команду в каталоге, где она находится (это вы уже пробовали, см. ниже об этом).
2. указывать полный путь к команде, т.е. выполнять команду `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin\keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 20000`
3. добавить путь к команде (т.е. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin`) в переменную окружения PATH

Программа генерирует ключ и сохраняет его в файл, который вы указали в командной строке (`my-release-key.keystore`). Так как указано только имя файла, без полного пути, то программа будет сохранять его в текущую директорию. Именно из-за этого не работает первый способ (у вас нет прав писать в `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin`). Исправить можно указав полный путь к файлу, при этом место должно быть доступно для записи вашему пользователю.